# Could pycuda and tensorflow work together?

Tags: python, tensorflow, pycuda

once tensorflow be active. it will make every cuda code crash even I use `sess.close()`...

the error msg is:

> pycuda._driver.LogicError: cuFuncSetBlockShape failed: invalid
>   resource handle

The following code it a simple example cuda code run by pycuda:
Once I add `sess = tf.Session()`. My cuda code crash. It work fine without `sess = tf.Session()`.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import pycuda.autoinit
import pycuda.driver as drv
import numpy
from pycuda.compiler import SourceModule
mod = SourceModule("""
__global__ void multiply_them(float *dest, float *a, float *b)
{
  const int i = threadIdx.x;
  dest[i] = a[i] * b[i];
}
""")

## tensorflow will make any other cuda code crash............
sess = tf.Session()
sess.close()
## tensorflow will make any other cuda code crash............

multiply_them = mod.get_function("multiply_them")
a = numpy.random.randn(400).astype(numpy.float32)
b = numpy.random.randn(400).astype(numpy.float32)
dest = numpy.zeros_like(a)
multiply_them(drv.Out(dest), drv.In(a), drv.In(b), block=(400,1,1), grid=(1,1))
print (dest-a*b)
print("finish")
```

Any suggestion? Thanks~~~

Comment: Did you figure out what went wrong by any chance? I'm facing the same issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I suspect same problem as here: [Could pycuda and scikit-cuda work together?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72218532/deleting-an-fft-plan-in-scikit-cuda-destroys-the-pycuda-context)

Short answer: Do not use `import pycuda.autoinit`; this creates a new CUDA context that you would have to manage (push and pop) manually.

Instead, use `import pycuda.autoprimaryctx` to retain the already existing primary CUDA context that most other CUDA applications use automatically.