# Deleting an FFT plan in scikit-cuda destroys the pycuda context

Tags: pycuda, incompatibility, scikit-cuda

I would like to use [pycuda](https://github.com/inducer/pycuda) and the FFT functions from [scikit-cuda](https://github.com/lebedov/scikit-cuda) together. The code below

- creates a `skcuda.fft.Plan`,
- deletes that plan and then
- tries to allocate a `pycuda.gpuarray.GPUArray`.

```py
import pycuda.autoinit

import numpy as np
import pycuda
import skcuda
import skcuda.fft as cufft

plan = cufft.Plan((2,2), np.complex64, np.complex64)

del plan # equivalent to `skcuda.cufft.cufftDestroy(plan.handle)`
#skcuda.cufft.cufftDestroy(plan.handle) # equivalent to `del plan`

pycuda.gpuarray.empty((2,2), np.float32)
```

The last line throws `pycuda._driver.LogicError: cuMemAlloc failed: context is destroyed`.

Somehow, `skcuda.cufft.cufftDestroy(plan.handle)` also destroys the pycuda context (which is of type `pycuda._driver.Context`).

Can somebody see a good fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The master replied (https://github.com/inducer/pycuda/discussions/356):

> By using pycuda.autoinit, you're putting pycuda in charge of context management. That's not typically a good recipe for interacting with libraries that use the CUDA runtime API (like cuFFT, to my understanding). You might be better off retaining the "primary context" made by/for the runtime API and using that instead.

- Essentially, CUDA has a thing called [primary context](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-driver-api/group__CUDA__PRIMARY__CTX.html#group__CUDA__PRIMARY__CTX) that is "unique per device" and that can be retained and released.
- This is different from [ordinary contexts](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-driver-api/group__CUDA__CTX.html#group__CUDA__CTX) that can be created and destroyed.
- See also [this forum discussion](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/multiple-cuda-contexts-per-device-in-a-single-process/42429) on the difference and why it exists.
- [The relevant section](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#context) of the CUDA programming guide makes context management clear.
- The sections [Initialization](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#initialization) and [Interoperability between Runtime and Driver APIs](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#interoperability-between-runtime-and-driver-apis) complete the picture of how device contexts are created and used.

The solution to my specific problem above is retaining the primary context instead of letting pyCUDA create a new context. The easiest way to do this is via:

`import pycuda.autoprimaryctx` instead of `import pycuda.autoinit`

Voila, everything works now. See also [the documentation](https://documen.tician.de/pycuda/util.html#module-pycuda.autoprimaryctx) and [the code](https://github.com/inducer/pycuda/blob/main/pycuda/autoprimaryctx.py) for `pycuda.autoprimaryctx`.